# How to edit line shapefile with many segments to single segment?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, line, editing

As title, I have one line shapefile with many segments:

[image]

How to use QGIS to quickly edit this line shapefile and output a new file looks like the original one, but with only one segment (its attribute table only has one row)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new field of integer type and give one value for all rows in this field. Then use dissolve tool from `Vector -> Geoprocessing tools -> Dissolve`, if you are using QGIS 2.14.7, and select the NewField as a base to dissolve your polygons. If you are using QGIS 2.16.3, then go to `Processing toolbox -> QGIS geoalgorithms -> Vector geometry tools -> Dissolve`.

Or you can use `Singlepart to multipatrs tool` from `Vector -> geometry tools` and do the same process of selecting the new field with one value for all rows.

Comment: Thank you, it worked, but the manual of 'Dissolve' make me believe that the function only handle polygons.

Comment: Glad it worked.